# What wire is this?

Tags: electrical

it goes from the utility lines to the home. I thought it was coax and when I snipped some of it I found this.

Telephone wire?

Has blue red white and orange cabling.

[image]

[image]

Comment: ...so why are you cutting utility lines you cannot identify before cutting them? Usually a bad idea. Likewise, where on the planet are you, as local "standards" vary a lot around the world?

Comment: @Ecnerwal I was quite sure it was coax... made a mistake! BC Canada

Comment: Yeah, snipping random wires can lead to a pretty nasty shock, like discovering coax is phone line, or it actually kills you. Please don't do that in the future, we want you to come back and ask more questions! And, I'd agree, I think that looks like POTS 4-wire phone line _except_ that outer housing looks really thick. Maybe that's a Canadian thing vs a US thing.

Comment: check for printing on outer jacket ... could be for telephone, intercom, door bell, furnace, etc

Comment: No printing on the jacket which is weird. Pretty sure its just phone.

Comment: I'd also lean toward telephone although (I don't know about Canada, but in the U.S.) the wires are usually red/green/black/yellow.

Comment: What is the scale in the photo? Outside diameter?

Comment: Quite possible that old Nortel used different colors than old AT&T for phone drop wire. Old Canadian phone guys would presumably know....